# Read-only filesystem error

Tags: 14.04, fsck

Frequently my Ubuntu 14.04 server filesystems changed to read-only.

I ran `fsck` and rebooted which solved my issue.

How to fix the issue permanently?

```
end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 65563152
Buffer I/O error on device sda5, logical block 1313602
lost page write due to I/O error on sda5
Aborting journal on device sda7-8.
Buffer I/O error on device sda5, logical block 1313603
lost page write due to I/O error on sda5
Aborting journal on device sda6-8.
Aborting journal on device sda5-8.
EXT4-fs error (device sda5) in ext4_reserve_inode_write: Journal has aborted
EXT4-fs error (device sda6): ext4_journal_start_sb: Detected aborted journal
EXT4-fs (sda6): Remounting filesystem read-only
EXT4-fs error (device sda5): ext4_journal_start_sb: Detected aborted journal
EXT4-fs (sda5): Remounting filesystem read-only
```

let me know for more info

thanks

Comment: please [edit] your question and provide relevant logs, to allow us understand the source of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You end up in read-only mode because of one or more inconsistencies in your (root) file system. If they keeps appearing you either have a bad habit of not shutting down your system correctly, or you have a bad disk that needs replacing.